# Add/Remove program on windows 7 is failing without message

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, windows-installer

I'm trying to uninstall a project wich is developed in Visual Studio and installed using the msi-file from the install project. I can find it in the list of install projects, but when I right click and choose uninstall program the application isn't uninstalled, and I don't get any message. I have no clue what to do so please help.

**EDIT:** I have tried to run `msiexec.exe /X{product code}`, but the program stills show up in the Add/remove program dialogue. I have also tried to remove the key, the one under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, in the register manually and that made it disappear from the add/remove program screen but I still couldn't install a new version.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was to use http://www.revouninstaller.com/ to uninstall the program. It seems like there were multiple registry entries that was wrong.

Then enable IIS 6 compatibility to be able to install, don't ask me why since I didn't have it enabled when doing the original install.

Comment: Hm.. not the complete solution because I still can't install the new version of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Previously I would have said to use the following tool:

[MsiZap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370523(VS.85).aspx)

But I'm not sure how well it works on Windows 7 having last used it on Windows Vista, it should be okay but the usual caveats probably apply!